# PHP login and registration - data not inserting into database (PostgreSQL)

Tags: php, html, database, postgresql

Just trying to make a simple app where you can register and then login, going to find out how to do the logout, welcome pages later. Literally just want to post data to database by having someone type in a username and a password.

I am new and have been trying to figure this out for days now. I don't know what's wrong with it.

[Here's my PostgreSQL database and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCfeQ.png)

Here's my code:

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if((!empty($username)) && (!empty($password))){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO public.users (username, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."','".md5($_POST['password'])."')";
    $ret = pg_query($dbconn, $sql);
    if($ret){
        
            echo "Data saved Successfully";
    } else {
        
            echo "Something Went Wrong";
    }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../assets/icon.gif">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>悲</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="audio-player-container">
    <audio id="player" src="../assets/sinners_lullaby.m4a" autoplay loop></audio>
</div>
<div id="sadtext">SAD SAD SAD SAD SAD SAD SAD</div>
<div id="display">
    <div><p id="audiomenutext">Audio Menu</p></div>
<div id="buttons">
    <li><button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button></li>
    <li><button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button></li>
    <li><button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('player').muted=!document.getElementById('player').muted">Mute/ Unmute</button></li>
</div>
</div>
<button id="login" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Register</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="../assets/onepunchman copy.gif" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

      <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input id="input" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
        
      <button id="logininmodal" name="submit" type="submit">Register</button>
      <label>
        <input id="input" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button id="cancel" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/home.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ro check POST data.
Change

```
if((!empty($username)) && (!empty($password))){
```

To

```
 if((!empty($_POST["username"])) && (!empty($_POST["password"]))){
```